# Handling FreeMaker template with Ktor Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, freemarker, ktor

I'm very new to `Kotlin` (and Java), as well as `Ktor` and `FreeMaker`, trying to make an app combining all of them, but looks I'm doing something wrong related to the `FreeMaker` templates manipulating.

My app structure is:

[image]

`template.ftl`:

```
<#macro mainLayout title="Welcome">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <title>${title} | Kweet</title>
</head>
<body>
HI
</body>
</html>
</#macro>
```

`index.ftl`:

```
<#import "template.ftl" as layout />
imported title: ${title}
<@layout.mainLayout title="Welcome">
<div class="posts">
    <h3 class="content-subhead">Top 10</h3>
</div>
</@layout.mainLayout>
```

`BlogApp.kt`:

package blog

```
import kotlinx.html.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.freemarker.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.host.*   // for embededServer
import org.jetbrains.ktor.netty.*  // for Netty
import org.jetbrains.ktor.application.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.features.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.html.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.routing.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.response.*

fun Application.module() {   
    install(DefaultHeaders)
    install(CallLogging)
    install(Routing) {
        get("/") {
           val model = mapOf("id" to 1, "title" to "Hello, World!")
           call.respond(FreeMarkerContent("index.ftl", model, "e"))
        }
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    embeddedServer(Netty, 8080, watchPaths = listOf("BlogAppKt"), module = Application::module).start()
}
```

`build.gradle`:

```
group 'Example'

version 'alpha'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version  = '1.1.4-3'
    ext.ktor_version    = '0.4.0'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'


sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url  "http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/ktor" }
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlinx" }
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.ktor:ktor-core:$ktor_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.ktor:ktor-netty:$ktor_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.ktor:ktor-html-builder:$ktor_version"

    compile "org.jetbrains.ktor:ktor-freemarker:$ktor_version"

    compile "org.apache.commons:commons-email:1.4"
    compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.25"
    compile "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.1"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
kotlin {
    experimental {
        coroutines "enable"
    }
}


jar {
    baseName 'abc'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'blog.BlogAppKt'
    }

    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```

I got the below output upon starting the server:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer [here](http://ktor.io/features/freemarker).

[Template Loading](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_config_templateloading.html) is required to be installed as:

```
import org.jetbrains.ktor.freemarker.*
import freemarker.cache.*; // template loaders live in this package

install(FreeMarker) {
    templateLoader = ClassTemplateLoader(TheApp::class.java.classLoader, "templates")
}
```

Then the  template saved in `resources/templates` can be loaded using `call.respond()` method:

```
val user = mapOf("title" to "Welcome guy", "name" to "user name", "email" to "user@example.com")
call.respond(FreeMarkerContent("index.ftl", user, "e"))
```

Where `index.ftl` is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <title>${title} | Kweet</title>
</head>
<body>

<@greet person="${name}"!/>

Your email address is ${email}

<#include "/copyright_footer.html">
</body>
</html>

<#macro greet person color="black">
  <font size="+2" color="${color}">Hello ${person}!</font>
</#macro>
```

I found [this](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_quickstart_template.html) also to be a good startup for learning FTL template.